# Sending data from one html file to another

Tags: html, ajax, jsp

I am creating a dashboard application in which i show information about the servers. I have a Servlet called "poller.java" that will collect information from the servers and send it back to a client.jsp file. In the client.jsp , i make AJAX calls every 2 minutes to call the poller.java servlet in order to get information about the servers.

The client.jsp file shows information in the form of a table like

```
server1        info

server 2       info
```

Now, i want to add one more functionality. when the user clicks on the server1, I should show a separate page (call it server1.jsp) containing the time stamps in which the AJAX call was made by calling.jsp and the server information that was retrieved. This information is available in my calling.jsp page. But, how do i show it in the next page.

Initially, i thought of writing to a file and then retrieving it in my server1.jsp file. But, I dont think it is a good approach. I am sure i am missing a much simpler way to do this. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .NET world, we use SessionState to maintain data that must persist between requests. Surely there's something similar for JSP? (The session object, perhaps.)

If you can't use session state in a servelet, you're going to have to fall back on a physical backing store. I'd use a database, or a known standard file format (like XML). Avoid home-brew file formats that require you to write your own parser.

Answer (score 1):

You should name your servlet Poller.java not poller.java. Classes should always start with an uppercase. You can implement your servlet to forward to a different page for example if sombody clicks to server1 then the servlet will forward to server1.jsp. Have a look at RequestDispatcher for this. Passing information between request's should be done by request attributes. if you need to retain the information over several request you could think about using session.